# How to edit MuiModal-root using Material-UI for React library?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using the latest version of Material-UI library for React and I am trying to add additional css to the MUI-Modal css class. (see screenshot)

[image]

I am using this modal https://material-ui-next.com/utils/modals/ I would like to add justifyContent en alignItems to the root where the Modal is rendered in Material-Ui.

I have read something about overwrite the root with the classes property in the following tutorial:

https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/

I tried to do the following things:

```
<Modal style={{ justifyContent: "center" }} open={open}>
 <div className={modalPaper}>
   <Typography variant="title" id="modal-title">
    Add a club
   </Typography>
  <Typography variant="subheading" id="simple-modal-description">
   Before you can continue you'll have to add a club to the backend
  </Typography>
 </div>
</Modal>
```

I also tried the classes property and the className..

```
classes={{root: { justifyContent: "center" }}
```

but it appears this doesn't affect anything at all.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Can you make a quick example here and I'll take a look: https://stackblitz.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of overriding the Modal component style is by using the `className` attribute. I assume you are using react-jss with material-ui-next so here is how you would do it:

```
const styleSheet = theme => ({
  customModalRoot: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
})

class YourComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props

    return (
      <Modal className={classes.customModalRoot} open={open}>
        <div className={modalPaper}>
          <Typography variant="title" id="modal-title">
            Add a club
          </Typography>
          <Typography variant="subheading" id="simple-modal-description">
            Before you can continue you'll have to add a club to the backend
          </Typography>
        </div>
      </Modal>
    )
  }
}
```

If you take a look here in Modal source code: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v1-beta/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/Modal.js#L278 you'll find that they use the props `className` you give to the component. That's the behavior they mention in their documentation you linked: https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-class-names.

If you want I also modified Material's codesandbox example from their documentation by adding a `background-color: red` to the modal backdrop using this technique: https://codesandbox.io/s/x73jr9my8o

Comment: This is exactly what I did @Jonas please have a look here: https://codeshare.io/5MAZRe

Comment: I fixed it myself, apparently I needed to make a new modalStyle.jsx where I load all my styles instead of send the styles that are applied to the dashboard component to the addModal component...

Comment: Ok great, I'm glad you got that figured out. Well done!